# Subtype of shared data contract

Tags: wcf

Following advices from people on the internet about service references, I got rid of them now and split the service/data contracts into a common assembly accesible by both the server and the client. Overall this seems to work really well.

However I’m running into problems when trying to use custom objects, or rather custom subtypes, in the service. Initially I wanted to define only interfaces in the common assembly as the contract for the data. I quickly learned that this won’t work though because the client needs a concrete class to instantiate objects when receiving objects from the service. So instead I used a simple class instead, basically like this:

```
// (defined in the common assembly)
public class TestObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the service contract (interface), I have a method that returns such an object.

Now if I simply create such an object in the service implementation and return it, it works just fine. However I want to define a subtype of it in the service (or the underlying business logic), that defines a few more things (for example methods for database access, or just some methods that work on the objects).

So for simplicity, the subtype looks like this:

```
// (defined on the server)
public class DbTestObject : TestObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public DbTestObject(string val)
    {
        Value = val;
    }
}
```

And in the service, instead of creating a `TestObject`, I create the subtype and return it:

```
public TestObject GetTestObject()
{
    return new DbTestObject("foobar");
}
```

If I run this now, and make the client call `GetTestObject`, then I immediately get a `CommunicationException` with the following error text: *“The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:09:59.9380000'.”*

I already found out, that the reason for this is that the client does not know how to deserialize the `DbTestObject`. One solution would be to declare the base type with the `KnownTypeAttribute` to make it know about the subtype. But that would require the subtype to be moved into the common assembly, which is of course something I want to avoid, as I want the logic separated from the client.

Is there a way to tell the client to only use the `TestObject` type for deserialization; or would the solution for this be to use data transfer objects anyway?

Comment: You're swimming against the current anytime you try to apply OO concepts like inheritance when using the message-based WCF framework. Using DTOs is usually the best practice when transferring data with WCF services and they fit the message passing metaphor more closely.

Comment: @SixtoSaez I thought so too, but it’s quite hard to get into it correctly when you haven’t been there before… :/

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can control how WCF serializes your object types if you implement a [custom serialization extension](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-Custom-Serialization-43b3ee7a) for instantiating your type instances. I'm not sure how you would describe the inheritance chain to the custom serializer (maybe through attributes) but it should be possible. Again, you're coercing inheritance on to message exchange patterns but if the will is strong.... :)

Comment: Haha, I don’t think the will is strong enough. And such required effort is usually a sign that my way is not common at all and I should look for something else instead :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sixto Saez has pointed out, inheritance and WCF don't tend to go together very well. The reason is that inheritance belongs very much to the OO world and not the messaging passing world.

Having said that, if you are in control of both ends of the service, KnownType permits you to escape the constraints of message passing and leverage the benefits of inheritance. To avoid taking the dependency you can utilise the ability of the KnownTypeAttribute to take a method name, rather than a type parameter. This allows you to dynamically specify the known types at run time.

E.g.

```
[KnownType("GetKnownTestObjects")]
[DataContract]
public class TestObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTestObjects()
    {
        return Registry.GetKnown<TestObject>();
    }
}
```

Using this technique, you can effectively invert the dependency.

Registry is a simple class that allows other assemblies to register types at run-time as being subtypes of the specified base class. This task can be performed when the application bootstraps itself and if you wish can be done, for instance, by reflecting across the types in the assembly(ies) containing your subtypes.

This achieves your goal of allowing subtypes to be handled correctly without the TestObject assembly needing to take a reference on the subtype assembly(ies).

I have used this technique successfully in 'closed loop' applications where both the client and server are controlled. You should note that this technique is a little slower because calls to your GetKnownTestObjects method have to be made repeatedly at both ends while serialising/deserialising. However, if you're prepared to live with this slight downside it is a fairly clean way of providing generic web services using WCF. It also eliminates the need for all those 'KnownTypeAttributes' specifying actual types.

Comment: That’s pretty cool, thanks for that. However it does not really solve my problem as it still requires the client to know the server’s subtype (i.e. the client needs to register the server’s type in the registry). I’m going to accept this answer anyway because it definitely helps, and I don’t expect a better solution for my problem anyway. I guess in the long run, it’s better to define common DTOs.

Comment: Yes it does require the client to know the subtype - the server and client both somehow have to populate their own Registry at each end. DTOs may well be a good option. The other possibility would be to go for a composition solution (rather than an inheritance one). This approach might work, if the server type has no additional data that needs to go back to the client beyond that contained in the base type.